# How much higher accuracy of train than test is enough to consider the model overfitted?

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, ensemble-learning, adaboost

Considering a dataset of 920 samples with 40 features in a binary classification problem. The dataset is the heart disease dataset publicly available [here.](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/heart+Disease)

I preprocessed the dataset discarding those features which contains >50% missing data. Those which contains < 50% I imputed it using MICE ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3074241. Then I bagged numerical data into categorical data by gathering the values in equal ranges and then encoding features by OHE. The info about the dataset is the following:

[image]

The models considered are:
Linear SVM, RBF SVM, Logistic Regression, KNN , Decision Tree , Random Forest

I tuned the parameters using RandomSearchCV:

```
> Model: SVC(C=0.1, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
  decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3, gamma=0.1, kernel='linear',
  max_iter=-1, probability=True, random_state=None, shrinking=True,
  tol=0.001, verbose=False)

> Model: SVC(C=10000.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
  decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3, gamma=0.0001, kernel='rbf',
  max_iter=-1, probability=True, random_state=None, shrinking=True,
  tol=0.001, verbose=False)

> Model: LogisticRegression(C=0.01, class_weight=None, dual=False, fit_intercept=True,intercept_scaling=1, max_iter=100, multi_class='ovr', n_jobs=1, penalty='l2', random_state=None, solver='liblinear', tol=0.0001, verbose=0, warm_start=False)

> Model: KNeighborsClassifier(algorithm='auto', leaf_size=30, metric='minkowski',
           metric_params=None, n_jobs=1, n_neighbors=65, p=2,
           weights='uniform')

> Model: DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=None,
            max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=10,
            min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
            min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
            min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, presort=False, random_state=None,
            splitter='random')

> Model: RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, class_weight=None, criterion='gini',
            max_depth=30, max_features='sqrt', max_leaf_nodes=None,
            min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
            min_samples_leaf=4, min_samples_split=2,
            min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, n_estimators=400, n_jobs=1,
            oob_score=False, random_state=None, verbose=0,
            warm_start=False)
```

I got the following scores (mean +/- std) in a 10-CV: 
[image]

It surprises me that the training accuracy and F-score is higher (specially in random forest) than the test one.

Besides I computed bagging algorithms by the same methodology (tuning the number of estimators with RandomSearchCV and having the base_estimator the previous models considered):

```
Model: BaggingClassifier(base_estimator=SVC(C=0.1, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
  decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3, gamma=0.1, kernel='linear',
  max_iter=-1, probability=True, random_state=None, shrinking=True,
  tol=0.001, verbose=False),
         bootstrap=True, bootstrap_features=False, max_features=1.0,
         max_samples=1.0, n_estimators=200, n_jobs=1, oob_score=False,
         random_state=36, verbose=0, warm_start=False)

Model: BaggingClassifier(base_estimator=SVC(C=10000.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
  decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3, gamma=0.0001, kernel='rbf',
  max_iter=-1, probability=True, random_state=None, shrinking=True,
  tol=0.001, verbose=False),
         bootstrap=True, bootstrap_features=False, max_features=1.0,
         max_samples=1.0, n_estimators=100, n_jobs=1, oob_score=False,
         random_state=37, verbose=0, warm_start=False)

Model: BaggingClassifier(base_estimator=LogisticRegression(C=0.01, class_weight=None, dual=False, fit_intercept=True,
          intercept_scaling=1, max_iter=100, multi_class='ovr', n_jobs=1,
          penalty='l2', random_state=None, solver='liblinear', tol=0.0001,
          verbose=0, warm_start=False),
         bootstrap=True, bootstrap_features=False, max_features=1.0,
         max_samples=1.0, n_estimators=100, n_jobs=1, oob_score=False,
         random_state=38, verbose=0, warm_start=False)

Model: BaggingClassifier(base_estimator=KNeighborsClassifier(algorithm='auto', leaf_size=30, metric='minkowski',
           metric_params=None, n_jobs=1, n_neighbors=65, p=2,
           weights='uniform'),
         bootstrap=True, bootstrap_features=False, max_features=1.0,
         max_samples=1.0, n_estimators=100, n_jobs=1, oob_score=False,
         random_state=38, verbose=0, warm_start=False)

Model: BaggingClassifier(base_estimator=DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=None,
            max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=10,
            min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
            min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
            min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, presort=False, random_state=None,
            splitter='random'),
         bootstrap=True, bootstrap_features=False, max_features=1.0,
         max_samples=1.0, n_estimators=500, n_jobs=1, oob_score=False,
         random_state=34, verbose=0, warm_start=False)

Model: RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, class_weight=None, criterion='gini',
            max_depth=30, max_features='sqrt', max_leaf_nodes=None,
            min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
            min_samples_leaf=4, min_samples_split=2,
            min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, n_estimators=400, n_jobs=1,
            oob_score=False, random_state=None, verbose=0,
            warm_start=False)
```

I got the following scores (mean +/- std) in a 10-CV:

[image]

It also surprises me that there is no so much improvement from single algorithms to bagged algorithms.

On the other hand I also tried AdaBoost with Decision Tree and Logistic Regression (same tuning of n_estimators and learning rate with Random SearchCV:

```
Model: AdaBoostClassifier(algorithm='SAMME.R',
          base_estimator=LogisticRegression(C=0.01, class_weight=None, dual=False, fit_intercept=True,
          intercept_scaling=1, max_iter=100, multi_class='ovr', n_jobs=1,
          penalty='l2', random_state=None, solver='liblinear', tol=0.0001,
          verbose=0, warm_start=False),
          learning_rate=10, n_estimators=600, random_state=38)

Model: AdaBoostClassifier(algorithm='SAMME.R',
          base_estimator=DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=None,
            max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=10,
            min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
            min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
            min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, presort=False, random_state=None,
            splitter='random'),
          learning_rate=0.01, n_estimators=200, random_state=34)
```

I also got the following scores:

[image]

Reading about ensembles methods one may believe that its accuracy improves from single models, however for logistic regression even worsen (just a bit) but still, for Decision Trees it does not really improved that much < 1%.

What could have happened? Am I overfitting?

Comment: You can do an empirical analisys or you can use cross validation train and test to minimize the changes of overfit. Another technique is to bootstrap the data, if it were possible.

Comment: Already made it. I will try to perform some kind of feature selection.

Answer (score -1):

The gap between train and validation isn't what overfitting is. If you work under that *incorrect* definition you'll almost always choose underfitted models.

An overfit model is one where another would yield equal or greater generalization (which validation loss proxies) with less memorization of training data (higher training loss).

Comment: A model can be overfitted & still generalize better than a simpler model.

Comment: If it generalizes better, it is not overfit, at least relative to that simpler model.

Comment: You have an idiosyncratic & nonstandard definition of overfitting.

Comment: No, this is the formal definition of overfitting. I suggest you research what it means and see if your opinion changes.

Comment: You need to provide a citation that it is the formal definition. I haven't seen that formulation before in various papers & books. Eg, your definition doesn't match descriptions in ESL ($\widehat{\rm Err}-\overline{\rm Err}$), or elsewhere. Steyerberg, *Clinical Prediction Models* (which I happen to have open for other reasons), states "A key threat to validity is overfitting, i.e. that the data under study are well described, but that predictions are not valid for new subjects".

Comment: Victor Lavrenko. Overfittings vs underftting https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j9_yzC-x-js&t=2s

Comment: You're taking that too literally.  That's just a definition he used for his class.  It isn't *the* definition.  I also put up definitions that I think will 'click' for students in my classes.  He also talks about "simpler" & "complex" models, and "rigid" & "flexible" models, but these aren't synonymous--that's fine, I do the same thing, but they're all just attempts to break through the conceptual logjam, they aren't meant to be taken as the final, perfect definition.

Comment: It seems like you're just arguing about semantics instead of the crux of my argument.

Comment: The point is, there is the kernel of a good answer, but the answer, as written, isn't really correct, & that's likely to be a disservice to people who come to this page in the future.

Comment: I agree that the model doesn't necessarily need to be simpler, so I removed it that word. But, I believe what I've stated now is what overfitting means.